# titanium mobile sdk not found error

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am trying to create a new titanium mobile project but it keeps bugging me with the below error message.

Could not locate a Titanium Mobile SDK at the given path

Kindly advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [Configuring Titanium Studio with the Platform SDKs](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/2.+Getting+Started+with+Titanium+Studio#2.GettingStartedwithTitaniumStudio-ConfiguringTitaniumStudiowiththePlatformSDKs) for settings.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to [install sdk 7 and 8.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234328/titanium-doesnt-recognize-android-sdk-on-windows)