# Titanium doesn't recognize Android SDK on Windows

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

Titanium doesn't recognize Android SDK on Windows

My problem is that Titanium Studio doesn't see my installed Android Platforms. I've tried removing and reinstalling everything via Titanium Studio but that won't make any difference.

Here's a screenshot of the SDK Manager: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHnUu.jpg

Titanium Studio Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVYI3.jpg

Titanium Studio Details:

```
Titanium Studio, build: 1.0.8.201201262211
Build: jenkins-titanium-rcp-master-136 (origin/master)
Date: 26 January 2012, 22:14:21
```

OS Information:
    Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
    6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601

Problem in Titanium Studio:

```
One or more pieces are missing from the Android SDK. 
It may be that the Android SDK is already installed 
and Titanium Studio cannot locate the directory, or
it may be that some additional components need to be installed.
Items required:
•An Android SDK is missing. Titanium requires Android platforms 2.1.* and 2.2.*
```

Comment: When this error appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just spent a couple days wrestling with this problem. The issue is with the latest version of the mobile sdk that you've installed. Titanium Studio actually uses the following script to validate the Android SDK path in the configuration window:

MAC path looks like this:

/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/sdk_version_number_here/android/avd.py

Based on your post, your path is probably something like:

C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\sdk_version_number_here\android\avd.py

If you browse to the folder and look for that script, it's probably missing. We just deleted that version of the sdk (for us it was 2.0.1.GA2). Then went to Help -> Check for Updates to reinstall the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing all the api levels. SDK level 10-15.
Hopefully that would help. I am also running Titanium on the same version of windows, and it works fine.

Comment: I've tried installing everything by selecting everything, and then selected "Accept All" when i get the popup..

Comment: do you have admin rights for the current logged in user, just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

This looks crazy, but you need to install sdk 7 and 8, with the google APIs. I think that they have code nested to these SDK. Check twice that you accept the licence with Google API.

Here is the complete guide of [installing Titanium with Android.](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Installing+and+Updating+Android+SDK)

Comment: I've even tried to install everything and select the "Accept All" checkbox to make sure i don't miss anything... :/

Answer (score 0):

I broke my head for 2 days on the very same problem, and the solution is quite simple:
Titanium 3.2 and above does not work with android sdk in Windows.

Downgrade to 3.1.3 and everything will be just fine

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version